# How to find memory allocations and leaks in iphone applications without using instruments?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, instruments

I am planning to create a iPhone/ipad application which can check for allocations and leaks of the applications available on the device. Currently i don't know whether there are any existing API's(which may be private since am not planning to submit it to app store) for achieving this.My thought may be bit crazy but can anyone lemme know whether it's feasible or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS applications are sandboxed -- one app can't look at the memory or resources of another. So there's no way you're going to be able to write an app that detects leaks in other apps. The story may or may not be different if you're willing to jailbreak your device, but finding information in that case will prove difficult.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 1: (got your question wrong!)**
Analyzing other apps within a iOS app is not possible on un-jailbreaked phones (sandboxing).
If you can do a jailbreak, try to compile valgrind on iOS (very hard!) and build a GUI (iOS app) around it.

if you search leaks in your app (different question):
For memory leaks you don't need API's.

I would recommend you...

1. ... use [ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).
2. ... use [valgrind](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/iphone/iPhone_Simulator_Valgrind.20081224.html) (popular c instrumentation framework) for iOS (simulator only).

When you find and fix leak in the simulator, the chance is >99.9% that they are also fixed on iOS device builds.

But why not using Instruments?

Comment: OP appears to be asking about finding leaks in *other* apps.

Comment: Yeah you reminded me about sandboxing....! just want to check with jailbreaked devices. Thanks for your immediate response.